# Unity_play video from the Android internal storage

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject in Unity with a videoPlayer component and I want to play  a video from the Android internal storage during run time and not from streamingAssets.

When I put /storage/emulated/0/myFolder/myVideo.mp4 to the url path of the video player it doesn't work. I can not find any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more helpful advice. Thanks!

Comment: I figure it out. I had to add permission to the manifest.

<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>

But I can not hear the sound of the video.

Comment: Hi there. The best procedure is to post this comment as an answer to your own question. You can then after a period of time accept the answer. Answering the question helps to ensure that it does not remain on the unanswered questions list. Regards.